# Could not submit app to iTunesConnect review

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store

I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11 and Xcode 6.4 6E35b, when i click the button submit for review in iTunesConnect it says this error "Apps and app updates submitted to app store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK".

I have no idea why this is happening, Xcode 6.4 is not a beta version, i downloaded it from AppStore, it's a public release. If anyone know about this help me out here.

When i tried through application loader :
INFO ITMS-90111: "Your app is built with a beta version of Xcode or iOS SDK. Only apps distributed for beta testing may be built with beta software. To submit an app for distribution on the App Store, you will need to build the app with release versions of Xcode and iOS SDK."

Comment: Clean your project and try again.

Comment: I tried creating a new build, and submitted with new build version, still the same

Comment: You can change the value for key "Bundle Version". For example, if you have 1.0.0, you can change it to 1.0.0.1 into info.plist

Comment: @DharmeshKheni changing the bundle version would solve the issue .??? I  tried with 1.0, 1.1, 1.2

Comment: Yes may be. I already added into comment.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Okay i am trying that one sec

Answer (score 1):

Another solution - use Application Loader:

1. Export your app as IPA, signed with provision profile for App Store
2. Open Application Loader (open Xcode, menu Xcode->Open Developer Tools->Application Loader
3. Sign in with your iTunes Connect credentials in Application Loader
4. Upload your app

PS: This way is also useful, when you have multiple iTunes Connect accounts for different clients, and you need often upload different apps for them

Comment: let me try and get back to you in a moment

Comment: INFO ITMS-90111: "Your app is built with a beta version of Xcode or iOS SDK. Only apps distributed for beta testing may be built with beta software. To submit an app for distribution on the App Store, you will need to build the app with release versions of Xcode and iOS SDK."

Comment: i dont know what is happening

Comment: I think you have 2 xcode in your Mac (beta and normal). Try to remove them, re-install Xcode from App store and try again

Comment: I have only one Xcode icon in my Applications folder :(

Comment: delete it and re-install

Comment: Using Application Loader does not fix this problem. If you see this comment please don't waste your time with this answer, it's effectively the same as uploading through iTunes Connect as the OP stated in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

We're having the same problem. It seems that Apple have just changed the definition of being 'built with beta software' to not just mean a beta version of XCode, but also a current version of XCode on a beta version of the Mac OS.

See a long thread of upset app developers on the Apple Developer Forums here:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12848

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, used to have the same problem for tvOS applications with last Xcode 7.2.1 from App Store. Downgrade the Xcode to 7.2 version had solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check This in your Code:

- Go to Project -> Info -> iOS Deployment Target
- Make sure it will be not below -> 5.1.1
- Set it with 6.0
- Clean project & try again

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I have key named  : InfoDictionary version : value is 6.0

Comment: @AppleKid do you have multiple Xcode versions installed ?