# App Store refuses my update after installing Xcode 11 beta with keeping Xcode 10.2

Tags: xcode

I installed Xcode beta 11 and kept the 10.2 version, I submit my apps for review but I get invalid binary even though I did build with Xcode 10.2. I even uninstalled Xcode 11 beta and the same thing. I have no idea what to do next

> ITMS-90111: Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with a beta version of Xcode or SDK. Apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the GM version of Xcode 9 and the SDK for iOS 11, tvOS 11, watchOS 4, or macOS 10.13 or later.

Comment: But this kind of thing _always_ happens when there's a new version (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361717/after-updating-to-xcode-10-2-invalid-toolchain-error-when-trying-to-submit-app?noredirect=1&lq=1) so this is really a duplicate.

Comment: @matt I did try that and nothing of the suggested answers helped

Comment: But a lot of the answer are, for example, "wait until this gets ironed out at the App Store end". You haven't done that. :)

Comment: Still, installing and launching Xcode 11 made a bunch of changes under the hood, and merely deleting the app doesn't undo them. You might have to remove and reinstall 10.2 or something. There are _lots_ of duplicates with _lots_ of tricks suggested. The point is, your question adds nothing new.

Comment: I see even though I waited few days btw, I will mark this as duplicate thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not submit app to iTunesConnect review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826088/could-not-submit-app-to-itunesconnect-review)

Comment: I also have MacOS beta and Xcode 11 beta....  We like to live dangerously...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Upload App With OS Beta**

Don't use Xcode beta

Archive the app; before start upload  go

> Window -> Organizer

Right click in your app

> Show in finder

Will open the folder and you go right click in your app  and select

> New Terminal Tab at folder

Now you will find the pList to change info

```
cd Products/Applications/“AppCompany”.app/
```

Finally will change your BuildMachineOSBuild

```
open Info.plist
```

Find the BuildMachineOSBuild and change to build  Mojave ( January 22, 2019 )

> 18D42

Comment: really life saving.... tried so many things... ultimately this worked.. very poor management from apple...

Comment: The best workaround there is, thank you sir. I linked your answer on Apple Developers forum for every one struggling with that bug.

Comment: Place app name in place of "AppCompany" without double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question was provided by Warren (aka dodgio) on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/174833#174833):

> This appears to be the app store thinking that the new OS X version
>   10.11.6 (15G1004) with security patch is a beta version of OS X.
>
> I was able to submit without warnings or errors by digging into the
>   .xcarchive and modifying the info.plist of the app.
>
> Change the key
>
> ```
> <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
>
>      <string>15G1004</string>
> ```
>
> to the value for the original 10.11.6
>
> ```
> <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
>
>     <string>15G31</string>
> ```
>
> Then export the IPA or submit to the app store as usual.

Comment: How to do it? Please explain step by step.

Answer (score 2):

App needs to be compiled with **release version of Xcode**, wait for GM(Golden Master) version.